# In Scala, when reading from a file how would I skip the first line?

Tags: scala

The file is very large so I cannot store in memory.  I iterate line by line as follows

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines) {
}
```

How can I specify that the first line should be skipped?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines.drop(1)) {
  // ...
}
```

`drop` will simply advance the iterator (returned by `getLines`) past the specified number of elements.